# Problem when scanning DHL labels Identcode C# XAMARIN EMDK

Tags: c#, xamarin, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I'm trying to scan a DHL label on a TC20 with the EMDK in a Xamarin application. Unfortunately, I am not getting any feedback. The barcode is called the Identcode. I can scan the barcode in the Zebra Demo App.

I've tried many different settings but unfortunately it doesn't work.
An image of the barcode to be scanned is attached.

```
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Enabled = true;
//config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Length1 = 55;
//config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Length2 = 55;
//config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Redundancy = false;
//config.DecoderParams.I2of5.ConvertToEan13 = false;
//config.DecoderParams.I2of5.ReportCheckDigit = false;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.SecurityLevel = ScannerConfig.SecurityLevel.Level3;
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKCLr.jpg)

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your specific question, but last time I worked with the Zebra TC20/21 (about 6 months ago), I found the Zebra Xamarin EMDK to be a bit unreliable and not well supported. Using the built in datawedge software/method with the android intent output was far more reliable for us. Also easier to diagnose issues as you either get the intent (therefore a problem in your code), or you don't get the intent and need to look at the settings in datawedge. Worth looking at if it's an option for you.

Comment: I have now built a working configuration on the device with the DWDEMO.
Unfortunately this does not work in XAMRIN with the EMDK.

`config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Enabled = true;
...I2of5.Febraban = false;
...I2of5.VerifyCheckDigit = ScannerConfig.CheckDigitType.No;
...I2of5.Length1 = 6;
...I2of5.Length2 = 55;
...I2of5.Redundancy = true;
...I2of5.ReportCheckDigit = false;
...I2of5.SecurityLevel = ScannerConfig.SecurityLevel.Level1;                            
...I2of5.ConvertToEan13 = false;
...I2of5.ReducedQuietZone = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. I have a loop in which I check the status of the scanner and reset it to read. This means that there is no interruption to set the configuration.

Here is my working configuration for DHL Identcode.

```
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Enabled = true;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Febraban = false;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.VerifyCheckDigit = ScannerConfig.CheckDigitType.No;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Length1 = 6;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Length2 = 55;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Redundancy = true;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.ReportCheckDigit = false;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.SecurityLevel = ScannerConfig.SecurityLevel.Level1;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.ConvertToEan13 = false;
config.DecoderParams.I2of5.ReducedQuietZone = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set VerifyCheckDigit to 'no' to decode this barcode as I2of5: https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/7-0/api/barcode/ScannerConfig_DecoderParameters+I2of5Decoder/#verifycheckdigit

Comment: config.DecoderParams.I2of5.VerifyCheckDigit = ScannerConfig.CheckDigitType.No;

Unfortunately does not work